# Why didn't they stay in the town?

Tags: zombie, dawn-of-the-dead

In *Dawn of the Dead (1978)*, our heroes fly over a town where people are shown having fun and shooting the zombies for sport.

Why didn't they just settle down in the town? It seems rather secure, with very little zombies around and people armed with big guns. They don't seem to lack food either since they are partying.

Comment: Please may someone explain why this is considered opinion based?

Comment: I personally feel that it potentially isn't, especially if there's some commentary or novelization that covers this, but if not, I could see where almost all answers will have more to do with "this is what I think someone would do in this situation" rather than basing it on the setting.

Comment: Because Script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the film's [official novelisation](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3130938-dawn-of-the-dead), ostensibly written by Romero himself, their goal was to keep moving away from the hazard, using the helicopter as their primary mode of transport. Noting that they're already low on fuel, landing would mean ceding control of the chopper to the army units and putting them totally at their mercy.

> Both men were talking loudly over the drone of the engine and were
> also trying to talk one another down. Their strident voices woke Roger
> up. He turned just as Steve told the others, **“We’re pretty low on
> fuel. I’m just waitin’ for full light so we can see what we’re landin’
> in.”**
>
> The three other passengers looked down on the ground and could make
> out several large fires, probably warehouses and factories. The
> pea-green trucks of a National Guard convoy were also visible as they
> chugged up a winding country road.
>
> As the sun rose higher, more and more activity was visible on the
> ground. Search and destroy units made up of police, guardsmen and
> civilian volunteers moved across the countryside. Occasionally, a lone
> zombie could be seen wandering or staggering through the trees or over
> a field. Frequently, the creature was met by the staccato beat of
> gunfire as it was cut down.
>
> **“Jesus,” Roger said, rubbing the sleep from his eyes as he watched the
> horror show below. “It’s everywhere.”**
>
> “We’re getting pretty close to Johnstown,” Steve told him. “We’re
> better off away from the big cities. This map says there’s a little
> country airfield in Beaverdale. I’m goin’ to try and land there to
> refuel.”
>
> <sub><sup>[Dawn of the Dead: Official Novelisation](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3130938-dawn-of-the-dead)</sup></sub>

It's pretty clear that the occupants of the helicopter don't view what's happening below as a desirable place to be.

Comment: That explains it

Comment: @Hi0401 - [You are, as always, very welcome.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3iYzyDQ3hQ)

Comment: Thanks man I appreciate it :)